# Python - Variable won't print? (Trying to get variable outside of while/if, etc.)

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
global dir_name
dir_name = ''

def generateDirectoryName(newpath, x=0):
    while True:
        dir_name = (newpath + ('_' + str(x) if x != 0 else '')).strip()
        if not os.path.exists(dir_name):
            os.mkdir(dir_name)
            #1
            #print(dir_name)
            return dir_name
        else:
            x = x + 1


def createDirectory():
    generateDirectoryName(newpath)


def main():
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    createDirectory()

#2
print(dir_name)

main()

#3
print(dir_name)
```

When I try the code, the two `print`s at the end (labelled with comments `2` and `3` don't appear to have any effect. However, if I uncomment the `print` inside the function (at comment `1`), it will show the `dir_name` value. Why does this happen - why can't I access `dir_name` outside the function? How can I fix the problem?

Comment: You don't declare a variable global in the global scope, you use it _inside_ a function to tell Python you want to use the global version of that variable and not shadow it within a function. So the print statment at #1 gets the correct, _local_ `dir_name`, but the other two get the global, empty one.

Comment: Your first line within the function and before the while loop should be `global dir_name`. The global declaration that you have currently written does nothing

Comment: You should place `global dir_name` at the top of your `generateDirectoryName` function.

Comment: Thanks to you both!  When I set the global dir_name in the function above the while, it still doesn't print at #'s 2 or 3.  It gives me an error:  NameError: name 'dir_name' is not defined

Comment: @JM1 How exactly have you implemented it? Seems to work fine for me. Your code should look like what Usman answered.

Comment: I posted an update after comments section that shows you what I tried.   Thank you for your help.

Comment: Usman's answer worked.  Thank you both for your help!

Comment: Based on Usman's answer, I didn't have the variable dir_name = '' defined before the function after moving global = dir_name inside the function , that appears to be why it didn't work.

Comment: You may be new to Python, but you are not at all new to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, though: please do not "update" questions to show how you fixed the problem, do not tell us about your level of expertise (or anything else that is not about **the question** in the question); try to explain clearly and ask directly; [try to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) look for [existing answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+%5Bpython%5D+global) first; don't post "Thanks" comments; and above all keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dir_name is a local variable in your function. In order to change it to global you have to use global dir_name inside the function. As far as printing goes, dir_name is actually getting printed at 2 and 3 but is just an empty string. Also, you dont have to return dir_name as you're not assigning the return value of generateDirectoryName(newpath, x=0) to anything in createDirectory. Here is an updated version of your code:

```
dir_name = ''

def generateDirectoryName(newpath, x=0):
    global dir_name
    while True:
        dir_name = (newpath + ('_' + str(x) if x != 0 else '')).strip()
        if not os.path.exists(dir_name):
            os.mkdir(dir_name)
           #1
            #print(dir_name)
            return
        else:
            x = x + 1


def createDirectory():
    generateDirectoryName(newpath)


def main():
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    createDirectory()

#2 (This will still print an empty string)
print(dir_name)

main()

#3 (This will print whatever is printed in #1)
print(dir_name)
```